# How to make an validation select option using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I tried to make a validation using javascript but I had some trouble if I leave the field empty it shows the message, then select an item in the list but it now shows an empty message and the action isn't executed. If I click the button twice, it will go trough

I put some code :

- html :

  ```
  <select name="condition[]" class="search_test col-sm-6 form-control condition" style="line-height: 34px;" oninput="InvalidCondition(this)" oninvalid="InvalidCondition(this)" required>
    <option value="" selected="selected" disabled>Select Condition...</option>
      <?php foreach ($condition as $c) : ?>
        <option value="<?= $c; ?>"><?= $c; ?></option>
    <?php endforeach ?>
  </select>
  ```
- Javascript :

  ```
  function InvalidCondition(select) {
    if (select.value === "") {
      select.setCustomValidity("Please select an item");
    } else {
      select.setCustomValidity("");
    }   
  }
  ```
- pictures :

[image]

[image]

Comment: you are setting empty value in else part, that's why it showing empty in message.please remove else condition :)

Comment: If I remove that else statement the button cannot go to action just looping in text "Please select an item"

Comment: in that case just attach value in else part . like select.setCustomValidity(select.value) , i didn't understand fully,but you can try it .

Comment: If I want to make a else condition to redirect to my action what should I do? I already make another method but still error

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the `else` condition there?

Without seeing context, will this work:

```
function InvalidCondition(select) {
  if (select.value === "") {
    select.setCustomValidity("Please select an item");
  } 
}
```

edit:

It would help if you provided a link, or perhaps more code, maybe Codepan.
In the meantime, does this work for you:

```
function InvalidCondition(select) { 
  if (select.value === "") { 
    select.setCustomValidity("Please select an item"); 
  } else { 
    select.setCustomValidity(`${select.value}`); 
  } 
}
```

Comment: Just an looping text "Please select an item" cannot go to action

Comment: my code in my question bro, you can see that code, I just use html and js